# Google Photos sucking up all storage

Tags: google-drive, google-photos, online-storage, image-storage

I'm using Google Photos to back up my photo and video library.
It's set up to store data as "high quality - unlimited storage".

However, it's complaining about exceeding my storage quota in the [Google One storage](https://one.google.com/storage) page:

[image]

Why is that happening?

Furthermore, everytime I launch Google Backup and Sync, it creates a folder under Google Drive called "Computers", where it adds all photos and videos. How can I add it only to Photos using the free space?

[image]

---

[image]

It seems that you can only backup and sync files to both Photos and Drive. Can't I disable the Drive sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google One recently introduced a new feature where you can manage all storage, via [this](https://one.google.com/storage/management) page:

[image]

Though it seems you cannot download or preview those photos prior to erasing them.

Answer (score 0):

This helped save some data, but wasn't a proper solution.

[image]

This is yet another solution. Very tedious to work with but is helpful. A proper hassle-free solution to compress all existing data and automatically convert it into high-quality data that doesn't count toward my quota, doesn't seem to exist at the moment.

[image]

Still it's definitely not the reported 4GB of data.